# Delete all rows except rows with specified entries

Tags: mysql, rows

I'm need to basically wipe my MYSQL database except for very specific entries. I would like to use data from these rows to prevent them from being deleted by the delete all query.

My GoogleFu isn't quite strong enough and this is the only starting point I have:

```
    delete from YourTable 
    where id not in
    (
    select ID 
    from YourTable
    LIMIT 200
    )
```

Now I know this is to delete all except for 200 entries but of course this isn't what I want to do, but it has the format that I figured I would need. This is a great start, but I need to stop the deletion of any rows that contain unique data entries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply using not equals or not in?  You don't specify the criteria, but perhaps this will work:

```
delete from YourTable
    where id not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

If your criteria is more complex, you can use `or`:

```
delete from YourTable
    where col1 = 'Lucy' and col2 = 'Ricky' or
          col1 = 'Fred' and col2 = 'Irma' or
          col1 = 'Thurston' and col2 = 'Lovey';
```

Comment: Your first example is exactly what I needed! I was probably trying to make it too complicated than what it really needs to be. Thank you for helping out this young MYSQL newbie.